# Generate CATransform3D using two CGrect s?

Tags: ios, matrix, cgaffinetransform, cgrect, catransform3d

I have 2 rects: initial and destination ones.

How to create CATransform3D/CGAffineTransform (or transform matrix) which will resize a view from the initial rect to the destination one?

As I understand I should take the initial rect and translate it to (0, 0). Then I should resize the result to the destination rect and then I should move the result to the origin of the destination rect. Although even if this reasoning correct I always make some mistakes in these calculations and I can't achieve the correct result even for origin point.

Comment: Are you only planning on scaling and translating the rectangle? Also, is the transform relative to the first rectangle or some common parent?

Comment: Yes, I plan to scale and translate only. I had some problems when I tried to animate CATransform3D/CGAffineTransform and frame simultaneously. So I want to replace them with one complex transform. And I can't understand your second question. I have a view with the initial frame placed on the parent view which has frame `CGRectMake(0, 0, deviceWidth, deviceHeight)` and I want to apply to it a defined transform to make it look liked the same view but with the destination frame.